# Can a server with no public IP interface be a NAT?

Tags: nat

Dear networking experts

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 instance in a cloud (say A), that is assigned a public ip address an can be logged in from internet, however its only network interface is private:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:0d:5d:03:3c:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.17/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global eth0
```

I understand that the cloud provider is doing the NAT for me.

Now I have another VM, say B, without such NAT in the same private subnet, and B can't be accessed from internet, neither can B reach public servers.

Now, I would like to use A as a NAT or router to access internet from B. I assume that if I can reach internet from A, then I can somehow set it up to forward traffic from B.

However traditional NAT recipes for A (such as in man ufw-framework) don't seem to work for me, since I guess they assume that A should have a real public IP on an interface.

So, the question is - is it possible to provide B with internet via A in the setup I described?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Surely you can do another NAT in addition to what your provider does.

`ufw` is just a netfiter script generator. If it isn't able to do its work, throw it away, it only obscures things.

To do NAT, you only need a single rule in the firewall:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

That's it. This system now will masquerade (NAT) a traffic for any other system, even if traffic subjected to translation comes from eth0. You will need to specify its IP address as a gateway on all other systems.

If you go this route, you also need to manually enable ip forwarding (`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`), disable redirects on all systems (see `..._redirects` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`) and enable rules saving/autoloading (with `netfilter-persistent` and `iptables-persistent` packages).

Also, beware of security! If this network also holds machines not under your control, you must filter them in the `filter` table, `FORWARD` chain (just permit forward for your machines and disable it for everything else with the policy). Also you can control (filter) access to this NATing machine in the `INPUT` chain.